# ExpressJS always serving the index

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, static-files

So I have a problem with my react SPA. I created it using `create-react-app` and all the built files (including the index.html, all js, css and images) are collected in the `build` folder.

The server is set up in two parts.

First is the nginx webserver.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl ;

    server_name beta.frpgame.ru;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/frpgame.ru/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/frpgame.ru/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    access_log /home/malkav/demiurge/client/logs/access.log;
    error_log  /home/malkav/demiurge/client/logs/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name beta.frpgame.ru;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://beta.frpgame.ru/$1 permanent;
}
```

Second is the `ExpressJS` server that the `nginx` server proxies to.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const compression = require('compression');
const port = process.env.NODE_PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('App is listening on port ' + port);
```

When you load the website in your browser (the host name is listed), it looks pretty normal, images and scripts work as expected. But on the first load and after a new deploy it may take 2 or 3 tries. I believe it's because the static files on the server are for some reason not accessible via direct link. If you try to load an [image](https://beta.frpgame.ru/images/snake_white.png) or css/js file, you'll get the `index.html`.

I have already tried mocking with the line order in the `server.js` but with little to no result. Changing to `app.get('/' ...` doesn't change anything either.

Comment: shouldn't it be: `app.get('/', ..)`

Comment: @Milan would it work with routes?

Comment: Route path '/' will match request to the rootRoute , using`/*` will match all paths routes and return index.html for all of them

Comment: @Milan that's the problem, the site has client-side routing. 
Also, tried removing the `*`, it changed nothing...

Comment: Does it eventually correct itself?

Comment: Well, eventually the site loads fine, but direct link - no.

Comment: @Almaron - I've just tried your image link it does load the image

Comment: @Milan... how on earth....

Comment: Are you sure you don’t have some caching issues with your browser?

Comment: I have cache disabled through DevTools. And opening it in an incognito tab doesn't help.

Comment: Did you try with `app.get('*', ...` ?

Comment: The problem _sounds_ like your static route isn't quite setup correctly then, but as per @Milan I can also see the image you've linked ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to pure NGINX setup and removed the node server alltogether.
I'll need to get it back once I get to SSR, but that'll be another story.